# LINQ getting an item <t> from a collection

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I need to receive a type  from some LINQ which is assigned to a var at run-time, obviously, I could cast the var to my type myself, but I believe the LINQ is wrong, (maybe missing the Select?) can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

----- Code  ------

```
   // there is only one active flag which is true in the collection...
    var selected = m_PersonCollection.Where(t => t.Active == true)

   // Thinking this is the way it is done...
    Person person = selected as Person;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var selected = m_PersonCollection.Where(t => t.Active == true).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: For reference, from the multiple answers if your getting a single type then obviously you dont need the var as the runtime will know the type, so use the type name and not var with the above, but the answer is still right

Answer (score 6):

Your code returns a list of all `Person` where `Active == true` if you want to get single person you can use

```
var selected = m_PersonCollection.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Active == true)
```

or if there can be only one active person

```
var selected = m_PersonCollection.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Active == true)
```

in both cases `selected` will be single `Person` object, or null if none found

Answer (score 5):

To get one item from the collection you can use `FirstOrDefault`

```
Person person = m_PersonCollection.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Active)
```

This will give you the first person found or `null` if no persons were found.

Answer (score 3):

The [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return `IEnumerable` but not the `Person`, use `FirstOrDefault` or `Single` to get object of type `Person`.

```
var selected = m_PersonCollection.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Active == true);  
Person person = selected as Person;
```

Comment: No need to use '== true' and the last cast. 'selected' is already a Person.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what kind of data erson has but no need to use var and casting. try this one

```
Person  objPerson = (from person in m_PersonCollection
                         where person.Active.Equals(true)
                          select new Person
                          {
                              // map your Person here
                              //I assume Person has name property
                                name = person.Name
                           }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I like this as you have used the type  so you dont need to cast, and even though the linq is correct, i just dont like how it is formatted! cheers!